# How to set a Ext.form.ComboBox default value from JSON?

Tags: json, extjs, combobox, sencha-touch

I know that this is a simple question, but I got stuck looking for a solution.

First, I got the FormPanel, that obtains data passed by JSON that looks like:

```
var formPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
....
[
{name: 'country', mapping: 'country'}
]
...
```

Then, I populate the store with data from an external file that has a list of countries

```
  var countryStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields: ['vcountry', 'vcountrydesc'],
    data : Ext.ms.data.countries,
    id:1,
    });
```

What I want to do is to set a default value in a Ext.form.ComboBox, which is defined as `name: 'country'`, precisely, I want to do something like this:

```
  var countryFld = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    store: countryStore,
.....
    mode: 'local',
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'Select Country',
    value: 'country', **<---I WANT TO DO THIS, BUT TO DISPLAY A VALUE, NOT A STRING!**
   ....
    }
    });
```

I assume that solution is very simple, but I got stuck on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIMPLE, very stupid of me to ask...
Solution is just like for any other form

```
dataIndex: 'country',
```

instead of

```
value:'country',
```